# Facebook Debugger - 403 Forbidden - Shopify Store

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, shopify, http-status-code-403

We ran our Shopify store URL through Facebook's Debugger because we've been having issues sharing the URL on Facebook. When I put my URL in - I get a 403 Forbidden in return along with the following message:

**Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed**
*Bad Response Code - URL returned a bad HTTP response code.*

**Errors That Must Be Fixed**
Missing Required Property - *The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.*

However, the 'og:type' property IS present, as well as all other required tags - as these tags are built into the theme we are using.

Facebook states it is a Shopify issue and Shopify points the finger back at Facebook. The bottom line is the website itself comes up with no issue and sharing on other social networks, such as LinkedIn, is no issue either.

The URL in question here is http://www.holeinthesheet.com. Try attempting to share this URL on Facebook and you will see what I mean.

Comment: The tags may be there, but as long as Facebook receives a 403 Forbidden when trying to scrape your site, they don’t matter – that 403 error is what you need to get fixed. And why your site responds with that status code, can only be investigated on your end.

Comment: I understand @CBroe, but NO ONE else gets this error and I've already contacted my host and did all sorts of testing on my end. Do YOU have any issues when attempting to access the website? Do you have any tool recommendations I can use to troubleshoot this? As I said before, if I share the URL on LinkedIn for example, there is no issue - it's only with Facebook and their Support team states the issues is not on their end. Really would appreciate any other recommendations / advice. Thank you.

Comment: Start by checking the log files to see what’s going on when the FB scraper makes its request.